# Gitlab error when pushing app to Azure Kubernetes Service: An image does not exist locally with the tag:

Tags: azure, gitlab, azure-aks

Absolute noob here to coding, recently taken up learning Kubernetes and Docker.
I'm trying to push the sample Azure Voting App https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-voting-app-redis from my Gitlab account to my AKS cluster, but end up with the error " An image does not exist locally with the tag:" "ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1"

Trying to push this directly from Gitlab to AKS.
I have the cluster configured properly, Helm Tiller and Gitlab-Runner installed and running

Detailed error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.9.0-rc2 (227934c0)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ...
Starting service docker:stable-dind ...
Pulling docker image docker:stable-dind ...
Using docker image sha256:b90ec7b4590e2638ed18d0afff2467a5eea36947c69439a188ed67c3d47e2ef2 for docker:stable-dind ...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ...
Using docker image sha256:d9fd699083aa4fe3f4dbdfb1b82d9ec79481505a2c64625b73459b27401c3560 for registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/auto-build-image/master:stable ...
Running on runner-72989761-project-11580529-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1553931660-8fbe33d6...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/username/azure-voting-app-redis/.git/
Fetching changes...
Created fresh repository.
From https://gitlab.com/username/azure-voting-app-redis
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
Checking out d5f5a8bd as master...

Skipping Git submodules setup
$ # Auto DevOps variables and functions # collapsed multi-line command
$ /build/build.sh
Logging to GitLab Container Registry with CI credentials...
WARNING! Using --password via the CLI is insecure. Use --password-stdin.
WARNING! Your password will be stored unencrypted in /root/.docker/config.json.
Configure a credential helper to remove this warning. See
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/#credentials-store

Login Succeeded
Building Heroku-based application using gliderlabs/herokuish docker image...
Sending build context to Docker daemon  88.06kB

Step 1/10 : FROM gliderlabs/herokuish as builder
latest: Pulling from gliderlabs/herokuish
6cf436f81810: Pulling fs layer
987088a85b96: Pulling fs layer
b4624b3efe06: Pulling fs layer
d42beb8ded59: Pulling fs layer
ea3549156eeb: Pulling fs layer
823b9a26dccb: Pulling fs layer
9a09076638c5: Pulling fs layer
00983af1e278: Pulling fs layer
3373d1a5c8b8: Pulling fs layer
0ea1a1ab15e5: Pulling fs layer
61926fcdb5a5: Pulling fs layer
50b2a348b8ef: Pulling fs layer
0d8c2d103a66: Pulling fs layer
d42beb8ded59: Waiting
ea3549156eeb: Waiting
823b9a26dccb: Waiting
9a09076638c5: Waiting
00983af1e278: Waiting
3373d1a5c8b8: Waiting
0ea1a1ab15e5: Waiting
61926fcdb5a5: Waiting
50b2a348b8ef: Waiting
0d8c2d103a66: Waiting
987088a85b96: Verifying Checksum
987088a85b96: Download complete
b4624b3efe06: Verifying Checksum
b4624b3efe06: Download complete
6cf436f81810: Verifying Checksum
6cf436f81810: Download complete
ea3549156eeb: Verifying Checksum
ea3549156eeb: Download complete
d42beb8ded59: Verifying Checksum
d42beb8ded59: Download complete
9a09076638c5: Verifying Checksum
9a09076638c5: Download complete
3373d1a5c8b8: Verifying Checksum
3373d1a5c8b8: Download complete
823b9a26dccb: Verifying Checksum
823b9a26dccb: Download complete
0ea1a1ab15e5: Verifying Checksum
0ea1a1ab15e5: Download complete
50b2a348b8ef: Verifying Checksum
50b2a348b8ef: Download complete
00983af1e278: Verifying Checksum
00983af1e278: Download complete
61926fcdb5a5: Verifying Checksum
61926fcdb5a5: Download complete
0d8c2d103a66: Verifying Checksum
0d8c2d103a66: Download complete
6cf436f81810: Pull complete
987088a85b96: Pull complete
b4624b3efe06: Pull complete
d42beb8ded59: Pull complete
ea3549156eeb: Pull complete
823b9a26dccb: Pull complete
9a09076638c5: Pull complete
00983af1e278: Pull complete
3373d1a5c8b8: Pull complete
0ea1a1ab15e5: Pull complete
61926fcdb5a5: Pull complete
50b2a348b8ef: Pull complete
0d8c2d103a66: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:1de05c84afa3abf1df66efca6a928d33ea142cd564b31c7e33d09c8104d8534a
Status: Downloaded newer image for gliderlabs/herokuish:latest
 ---> b4081fb3902d
Step 2/10 : COPY . /tmp/app
 ---> bee1861a2af1
Step 3/10 : ARG BUILDPACK_URL
 ---> Running in 416cf916d6b4
Removing intermediate container 416cf916d6b4
 ---> a8aef0bf8060

Step 4/10 : RUN /bin/herokuish buildpack build
 **---> Running in afc833232bea
       -----> Unable to select a buildpack
The command '/bin/sh -c /bin/herokuish buildpack build' returned a non-zero code: 1
The push refers to repository [registry.gitlab.com/username/azure-voting-app-redis/master]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: registry.gitlab.com/username/azure-voting-app-redis/master
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1**
```

Per the online quickstart guides, the app should be deployed and accessible, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong or missing here. I even have Docker installed and running locally on my laptop.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: i think this means what it means, there is no image tagged `registry.gitlab.com/username/azure-voting-app-redis/master` in the registry

Comment: any pointers on how do i fix this? I'm totally new to the developer side of things and would appreciate help in how do I go about solving this please.

Comment: upload\push that image to that repository

Comment: how? can't find anything that helps me understand how to do that online :(

Comment: never worked with gitlab runner, it appears to call some random script that doesnt tell what it does, but if that error is right, you need to build that image manually and push to that repo